# Ajax slideshow for D7?

Tags: 7, ajax, javascript

I am looking for some kind of Ajax-based slideshow/banner module for D7 for a changeable front-page photo banner. Unfortunately neither [Views Slideshow Ajax](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow_ajax) nor [Ajax Slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/ajax_slideshow) have been ported to D7 yet. I have several megabytes of photo content and would like to load each image on demand, not load them all at once (which is, as I understand, how most of the slideshow modules work). Right now I am just using a view that returns a randomly-chosen image, but I'd rather have it cyclable by the user with arrows or by a timer.

Are there any existing D7 modules that do something like this? There are so many slideshow, banner, and gallery modules: I may have missed the one I need.

Comment: Sounds like you need to create a custom module to achieve this. I created a module with similar principle in this site - http://m.cnngo.com (More button)

Answer (score 1):

The Views Slideshow module relies on the Cycle library, if I'm correct. It supports AJAX / progressive loading in it's current version as seen here:

- http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle2/demo/progressive.php

In my experience, a lot of Drupal modules make the integration of library options unneccessarily complex:
So you could just generate the necessary code via views instead and load the lib yourself via template. Most current slideshow scripts support AJAX loading, so you can choose one that suits you.